# EasyList read file for paring and formating file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hello I have a question for reading a file in python.

I am currently working on filter lists and would like to parse `http_request` through the EasyList.

I opend the File like this:

```
with open("EasyList.txt", encoding='utf8') as infile:
    filterList = BeautifulSoup(infile, "html.parser")
```

The format is like this:

```
&amp;ad.vid=$~xmlhttprequest
&amp;ad_block=
&amp;ad_box_
&amp;ad_classid=
&amp;ad_code=
&amp;ad_height=
```

I think I would need this kind of format in an array:

```
rules = [
    "&amp;ad.vid=$~xmlhttprequest",
    "&amp;ad_block=",
    "&amp;ad_box_",
    "&amp;ad_classid=",
    "&amp;ad_code=",
    "&amp;ad_height=",
    ]
```

Is there any easy way to read a `.txt` file and format it directly like this?

Comment: You mean that the content of file is in box that you mentioned "The format is like this:", and want to convert it to last box?

Comment: Yes, I just mean transforming the first format in the next array like format with commas and ""

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem:

```
import io

inpt='''&amp;ad.vid=$~xmlhttprequest
&amp;ad_block=
&amp;ad_box_
&amp;ad_classid=
&amp;ad_code=
&amp;ad_height=
'''

buf = io.StringIO(inpt)

out="rules = ["

line=buf.readline()
while line!='':
    out+='\"'+line[:-1]+'\",'+line[-1:]
    line=buf.readline()

#line=lin
out=out[:-2]+out[-1:]
out+=']'

print(out)
```